# Loop Bounds vs. Iteration Domain in Polyhedral optimization

Tags: optimization, arrays, loops, upper-bound, iteration

**Context:**

I was reading a tutorial on [polyhedral optimization](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/553703704). But got confused **while trying to translate the iteration domain (i.e. loop bound) to set builder notation.**

**Problem Description:**

*A code snippet from the article*;

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2*N; ++i)
    S: Z[i] = 0.;
```

The iteration domain for the statement 'S' is described with the set-builder notation as

`{S[i] : 0 ≤ i ≤ N}`. But the code says that i should go up to or equal to `2*N`.

**Example Case:**

Let’s consider the code given above. And also assume N = 5

Then this loop will iterate from `i = 0 to 10 (where, 2xN = 2x5 = 10)`.

But from the set builder notation, we can see that the iteration domain should be in the range of

`0 <= i <= N, i.e, 0 <= i <= 5`.

But considering the real code snippet,

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2*N; ++i)
    S: Z[i] = 0;
```

`i` go up to 10.

**So my doubts are…**

1. Then should I write the set builder as `{S[i] : 0 ≤ i ≤ 2N}`  or `{S[i] : 0 ≤ i ≤ N}`?
2. For now, even if both of them are correct; later are there any implications/issues that would arise? That I should be concerned on now? I am asking, because I have seen, that those notations are heavily used in forming systems of equations (To solve what, I don’t know yet )

Screenshots are attached from the tutorial for quick review.
Thank you.

[image: Shot1]
[image: Shot2]

Comment: I believe, these are just the notations. $D_S$ denote the set of $S[i]$'s specified by the range of $i$, i.e., $0 \leq i \leq N$. You can also denote $D_S = \{S[i] : 0 \leq i \leq 2N\}$ or $D_S = \{S[i] : N \leq i \leq 2N\}$; upto you.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami, I beg your pardon; I have edited my earlier question and made it more clear. I would greatly appreciate it if you could revisit my updated query on the list. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Both the notations $\{S[i] \colon 0 \leq i \leq 2N \}$ and $\{S[i] \colon 0 \leq i \leq N\}$ are correct. They just mean different. The first means the set $\{S[0], S[1], \dotsc, S[2N-1], S[2N]\}$ and the second means that $\{S[0],S[1], \dotsc, S[N-1], S[N]\}$.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami, If both notations are correct, then for the given example loop in the question, {S[i]: 0<=i<=N} is the correct one, Am I correct?

Comment: @KennethKho, I don't know what you are trying to say, but `S` and `T` are both supposed to indicate two different statements, whereas in both statements `Z` is the array. But, when they are writing iteration domain in set builder form `D_S`, that is technically supposed to indicate statement `S`. Whose loop bound in set notation does not match.

Comment: If `D_S` is supposed to indicate statement `S` instead of arbitrary statement, then only one is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is correct about $T$ but not $S$ since ${S[i] : 0 ≤ i ≤ 2N}$ and $T[i,j] : 0 ≤ i, j ≤ N$.

I believe a TL;DR of the question is in order, therefore:

1. What is the iteration domain of this loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2*N; ++i)
```

The answer is ${S[i] : 0 ≤ i ≤ 2N}$, and the article incorrectly says ${S[i] : 0 ≤ i ≤ N}$.

2. What is the iteration domain of this loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i <= N; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j <= N; ++j)
```

The answer is $T[i,j] : 0 ≤ i, j ≤ N$, and the article correctly says $T[i,j] : 0 ≤ i, j ≤ N$.